# Issue with Edge 44 and grid-template-columns: inherit

Tags: css, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, css-grid

I'm working on a layout that uses CSS-grid with breakout sections that use `grid-template-columns: inherit;`. Basically using the technique described in this article: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/breaking-out-with-css-grid-layout/

This works fine in major browsers, except for Edge 44, where `grid-template-columns: inherit;` seems to break the layout. If I simply copy the inherited value by hand, it displays fine.

Anyone know why this is happening, and if there is a way to fix it without manually duplicating the inherited values?

Here is a short code snippet showcasing the issue:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [full-start] minmax(2em, 1fr) [main-start] minmax(0px, calc(500px / 2)) [main-right] minmax(0px, calc(500px / 2)) [main-end] minmax(2em, 1fr) [full-end];
}

.breakout {
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: full;
  display: inherit;
  grid-template-columns: inherit;
}

.content {
  grid-column: main;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class = "breakout">
    <div class = "content">
      <p> This is the content inside the breakout element. It should sit properly within the grid, but for some reason it breaks in Edge 44. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

EDIT: Seems like the problem stems from inheriting with `calc()`. Possibly a bug?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem on Microsoft Edge 44 version, after testing, it seems that if we using `[full/main-start]` with `calc()`, it will show this issue on Microsoft Edge 44.

As a workaround, you could try to set a fixed size for the grid-template-columns minmax() function. Code as below:

```
    body {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: [full-start] minmax(2em, 1fr) [main-start] minmax(0px, 250px) [main-right] minmax(0px, 250px) [main-end] minmax(2em, 1fr) [full-end];
    } 
    .breakout {
        background: grey;
        width: 100%;
        grid-column: full;
        display: inherit;
        grid-template-columns: inherit;
    }

    .content {
        grid-column: main;
    }
```

Then the output as below:
[image]